Replacing if in ERB with a method
I want to replace this code
---
myyaml:
  me:
    :name: "John"
  text: |
    My name is <% if me %><%= me[:name] %><% end %>
---

With something like this:
---
myyaml:
  me:
    :name: "John"
  text: |
    My name is <%=greetings()%>
---

The idea is to define greetings function outside file and call as result_with_hash in ERB class.
The desired result is, obviously, My name is John.

Is the desired result that single line only or the whole multiline YAML string? Can you show how your YAML/ERB is currently getting evaluated?

One thing to note is ERB#result_with_hash states:(emphasis added)

result_with_hash(hash)
Render a template on a new toplevel binding with local variables specified by a Hash object.

So in your case you are trying to call a method greetings() which is fine and completely accessible but it negates any reason for using result_with_hash. If you wanted to you could use a local variable greeting instead and call the method to assign the value.
require 'yaml'
require 'erb'
yaml =<<DOC
---
myyaml:
  me:
    :name: "John"
  text: |
    My name is <%=greeting%>
---
DOC

# You used both String and Symbol keys would recommend picking one so this isn't as awkward
name = YAML.load(yaml).dig('myyaml','me',:name)

def greetings(name) 
  "#{name}!" 
end 

puts ERB.new(yaml).result_with_hash(greeting: greetings(name))
#=> ---
#myyaml:
#  me:
#    :name: "John"
#  text: |
#    My name is John!
#---

The other option would be to just use ERB#result rather than result_with_hash. Both result and result_with_hash will use the current binding so instance variables, local variables (not overridden by the Hash provided to result_with_hash) and methods are all accessible in the ERB template.
require 'yaml'
require 'erb'
yaml =<<DOC
---
myyaml:
  me:
    :name: "John"
  text: |
    My name is <%=greetings()%>
---
DOC

# You used both String and Symbol keys would recommend picking one so this isn't as awkward
@name = YAML.load(yaml).dig('myyaml','me',:name)

def greetings = "#{@name}!" 

puts ERB.new(yaml).result
#=> ---
#myyaml:
#  me:
#    :name: "John"
#  text: |
#    My name is John!
#---


What about two names: :name: "John" and :surname: Smith. And pass method with parameter as a key of hash in ruby. Something like <%= greetings(:name) %> or <%=greetings(:surname)%> which allways look at me data.
